# User should only be able to run SQL queries in Synapse workspace

Tags: azure-synapse

We have a special scenario in Azure Synapse Workspace where we want the user to only be able to query the data that in the dedicated SQL pool which is connected to the Synapse workspace.

We don't want them to create pipelines, change Synapse settings etc. We want them only to be able to query the data in the dedicated SQL Pool.

Would assigning the Role "Synapse User" be sufficient enough to do this?

Answer (score 1):

My thoughts are as long as the user needs to access the dedicated SQL pool , he/she can be granted access within the synapse pool directly and he/she can access it via SSMS/ Data studio.

https://www.sqlshack.com/dedicated-sql-pools-in-azure-synapse-analytics/

No need to access via synapse workspace itself.

Comment: No, we need them to do it through Synapse workspace only. Is there a different solution for this?